# How to totally remove unwanted contacts from hangout

Tags: google-hangouts

How to totally remove unwanted contacts from hangout. Totally clean out from hang out means - not appearing in archive, not appearing in block., not appearing in hidden.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible because when the Hangouts user is searching for a contact, the search results, according to [See people’s online status - Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3111918?hl=en), could include:

> - Your contacts
> - Your circles
> - People in your domain
> - People on Hangouts
> - People not on Hangouts